# Trouble with React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to make a very simple project as one of my first react projects ever. What i tried to accomplish is making a simple input and making it print itself as i type however it doesn't do anything. This is the code i wrote so far:

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header/Header';

function App() {

  const [userInput, setUserInput] = React.useState('')

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setUserInput(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header userInput={userInput} handleChange={handleChange}/>
      <h1>{userInput}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

```
import React from "react";
import './Header.css'

const Header = ({userInput, handleChange}) => {
    return (
        <div className="headerContainer">
            <picture>
                <img alt='Something' className="logo"></img>
            </picture>
            <div>
                <label>Event:</label>
                <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={userInput}/><br /><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Header
```

I tried debugging, asked ChatGPT and Googling.`

Comment: [your code in codesandbox works](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/admiring-sound-cxvmzs) - I removed the ".css" imports but the code you posted definitely works as you expect